# 14.10 GUI issue with 2560x1080 resolution Nvidia 346.22

Tags: drivers, nvidia, resolution, 14.10

I recent got a new monitor which support the 2560x1080 resolution and whereas it was fairly easy to get the new resolution working on Ubuntu by installing the 340.65 Nvidia drivers I am getting weird GUI flickering.

At first I thought it may be a problem with the Nvidia drivers so I upgraded them to the 346.22 Beta drivers but had no luck in fixing the problem. At this point it seems likely that the problems stem from the GTK controls with scrollbars being the most noteworthy as the content in the scrollbar will flicker and scroll back to a previous position. The issue also occurs when opening directories or clicking on files in Nautilus and will continue to flicker every time the cursor is moved and will only stop if I press any of the mouse buttons.

These problems only occur when I am using the 2560x1080 resolution and stop if I switch to 1920x1080 or any lower resolution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution to this problem and will proceed with how I came to solve the issue. The problem was not caused by the Nvidia driver or GTK like I originally thought but was due to an old bug in Compiz to do with the screen refresh rate on Nvidia cards as pointed out by [Mateusz Stachowski on Google+](https://plus.google.com/+MichaelLindman/posts/32JgFi3cuw7) who also provided a link to the [bug report on launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/269904).

The bug report had a potential fix proposed by Christopher Townsend on [comment number #329](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/269904/comments/329) in which he provided a link to a [PPA to patch the bug in Compiz](https://launchpad.net/~townsend/+archive/ubuntu/compiz-nvidia-refresh-test) (apparently the patch cannot be applied to the official Compiz package due to licensing issues).

To apply the patch simply add the PPA to your repository, then update and restart your system.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:townsend/compiz-nvidia-refresh-test
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo reboot
```

---

This bug has now been fixed in the most recent version of Compiz as of `1:0.9.11.3+14.04.20150122-0ubuntu1` and the patch above is not longer necessary to fix the issue. [Source](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/269904/comments/368)

The officially fixed package can be installed by running:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install compiz
```

or by running a standard update of Ubuntu with:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Comment: Just wondering, what will I have to do when ubuntu updates? Purge the compiz and go back to the old one ?

Comment: The patch is a new version of compiz. It should be listed as version `1:0.9.12+14.10.20140918-0ubuntu1+ppa2` instead of `1:0.9.12+14.10.20140918-0ubuntu1` and purging and reverting back to the older version would likely break the system again.